# JS findIndex method always returns -1

Tags: javascript, arrays

This:

```
const pageID: number = 4;
```

and this:

```
this.charts.findIndex((chart: IChart) => {
  return chart.pageID === pageID;
}));
```

`this.charts` is an array of `IChart[]` which contains:

```
[
     {
          "pageID": 3,
          "zoomable": false
     },
     {
          "pageID": 4,
          "zoomable": false
     },
     {
          "pageID": 5,
          "zoomable": false
     }
]
```

Amazingly, this always returns `-1`. Even if I change the value of `pageID` to `4` or `5`.

Usually this works, but it's driving me nuts. The only thing I am doing before trying to find the index is merging two arrays and removing duplicate values based on the `pageID` parameter, like this:

```
  let unique = {};
  this.charts = charts[0].concat(charts[1])
    .filter((chart) => !unique[chart.pageID] && (unique[chart.pageID] = true))
    .sort((a, b) => a.pageID - b.pageID);
```

The output of `this.charts` is the array pasted above with `zoomable` and `pageID` properties.

--

It's not rocket science even running the above in the proper sequence inside `node` returns the proper index which is `1` in my case. Does anyone have any insights on this issue?

*Note: this is running in a Cordova app on iOS wkwebview.*

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run just fine.

```js
const allCharts = [[
  { 'pageID': 3, 'zoomable': false },
  { 'pageID': 4, 'zoomable': false },
  { 'pageID': 5, 'zoomable': false }
], [
  { 'pageID': 3, 'zoomable': false },
  { 'pageID': 6, 'zoomable': false },
  { 'pageID': 7, 'zoomable': false }
]];

let unique = {};
const charts = allCharts[0].concat(allCharts[1])
  .filter(chart => !unique[chart.pageID] && (unique[chart.pageID] = true))
  .sort((a, b) => a.pageID - b.pageID);
  
const pageID = 4;

const idx = charts.findIndex(chart => {
  return chart.pageID === pageID;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(charts));
console.log('idx of pageId 4 is:', idx);
```